# Writing file to remote PC

Tags: c++

I am running some experiments on an embedded platform. The problem is, that the memory ressources are limited; hence, I am thinking of writing the output into a file on a remote
machine. I am wondering what is the best way to realise that? I am using C++ on the embedded platform. I was thinking of communicating over a TCP/IP socket with the host machine where I wanna store my file. Obviously, I would then also need to write a socket application for the host PC that handles the incoming data stream. But I am wondering if maybe WIN XP or Linux offers some kind of support for my needs so that I do not need to write a socket application for the host.

Thanks for some guideline in this matter.

Answer (score 3):

On the host:

```
nc -l -p 9999 > log.txt
```

Then from the embedded system write to port 9999 of your logging host.

nc is netcat and can be found in most (Linux) distributions or here : http://nc110.sourceforge.net/

Comment: next time I will spare myself writting a python tcp server ;)

Comment: Just as a note, netcat generally comes with an additional parameter to make it stay listening for another connection after it's serviced someone.  On my Ubuntu box, it's -k, and it'd look something like:

nc -lkp 9999 >> log.txt

That might help the experiment so you wouldn't have to keep restarting netcat.  And log.txt would just keep appending.

Comment: C++ novice here: can you give a simple example of how to write a line of text to port 9999 of the logging host?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem previously.  I decided to use [shfs](http://shfs.sourceforge.net/) to mount the remote file system and then just wrote to a file on it like normal.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the embedded program act as an FTP client and run an FTP server on the main machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Linux for Embedded Systems, look here for further infos:

[Open Directory Embedded Systems](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Software/Operating_Systems/Linux/Embedded/)

[Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_Linux)

There's a lot of work that was already done by someone else. If avaliable I would use 'scp' for your purpose. If not there try to solve it with C++ and TCP/IP socket.